# How to Create Base45 QR Code in Pyton on Our Own?

Tags: qr-code

There are a lot of services for creating your own QR code and there are different types in of QR codes that can be created.

For gr. pass certificate, and i know that when you scan the QR code it will appear something like this HC1:NHFDFGDF......, i also know this is encoded as base45.

What if we can create and generate a QR code and populate those fields name, date of birth, etc. So we generate our own QR Code, by entering this info, like if we have VCard, etc.

Is is possible without having access to public keys?

Disclaimer: For educational purposes only! :-)

Comment: Are you, between the lines, trying to circumvent a gr pass (Corona ?), "for educational purposes" - or do you have a question about [encoding something in base 45](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-faltstrom-base45-02.html) ?  In the first case, your question probably does not belong here.

Comment: It is the second case

Comment: In that case, split your job in two: 1) convert the data into base45-encoded data. 2) encode this data into a QR code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create such a QR code. There's an online tool to create the base45 encoded string from the JSON
vaccination data at https://dgc.a-sit.at/ehn/

On that page, there's a button leading to a "test suite" page which shows some QR codes generated this way. You can scan these with the CovPass Check app and check whether these certificates will be accepted.

Hint: they will not pass, as the private key is not valid. The CovPass Check app knows the public keys (these are not secret, and you can find them, for example, [here](https://github.com/HQJaTu/vacdec/blob/signature-verification/certs/Digital_Green_Certificate_Signing_Keys.json)) and tries to decode the signature. If the signature was encrypted with a valid private key (which the app does **not** know), decryption will succeed, the payload will be checked and the result of that check will be displayed. If the signature was encrypted with an invalid private key, decryption fails and the app will tell you that the certificate is invalid.

Now, obviously, if one of the private keys would be leaked, it could be used to [create valid certificates.](https://threatpost.com/eus-green-pass-vaccination-id-private-key-leaked/175857/) However, it appears that all counterfeit vaccination certificates so far have been issued by other means: (1) by "hacking" into the badly secured servers which issue the certificates, or (2) by bribing an employee of a pharmacy or a medical  doctor.

Option (1) had been used by some whitehat penetration testers to generate the certificates in the linked article (these are obviously fake, as the birthdates are wrong). That was for educational purposes, and they reported the issue to the relevant authorities.

Option (2) has happened at least once in Germany; the bribed employee generated maybe 1000 forged certificates in one night using the pharmacy's credentials. At a going rate of currently €450 (or more) for a forged certificate, this is a lucrative business. No wonder new vaccination conspiracy theories pop up every second now; this is FUD marketing at work.

Note that the linked article (from October 2021) mentions a price of €100 for a forged certificate. Apparently, people are now (December 2021) willing to pay more for forged certificates now. Well, it's still cheaper that buying a forged passport (€870) which confirms that you are "Mouse Mickey", born December 31st 2001.